# why there will be AccessViolationException when using struct rather than class

Tags: c#, c++-cli, pinvoke

When I pass in a `struct` to some `PInvoke` method, I will receive the error

> Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write
>    protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

When I use class, then it is OK.

I want to know any reason behind that?

Comment: That totally depends on the code in question.

Comment: If you pass a struct to a pass-by-value parameter, its value gets copied. If you pass a class, the reference to the class gets copied. In order to be able to give you a proper answer, we need to know the situation you're in.

Comment: Which method are you trying to PInvoke and what does your struct definition look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN states in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef4c3t39%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) article:

> By default, native and managed structures are laid out differently in
>   memory, so successfully passing structures across the
>   managed/unmanaged boundary requires extra steps to preserve data
>   integrity.

You will also find additional information that will come in handy when using PInvoke there.